# Remove breadcrumbs from WooCommerce Storefront theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In order to remove breadcrumbs from the Storefront theme, the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/#section-4) states to add the following in `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
```

I tried this in a child theme of Storefront and it doesn't work. Tracing back the `woocommerce_breadcrumb`, it seems to be added in `storefront_content_top` action (in the file `<storefront_dir>/inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-hooks.php`. I commented out the corresponding line and indeed the breadcrumbs are hidden.

However, to do this the right way, I try to disable it from the child theme using

```
remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10 );
```

but it doesn't work. I should clarify that I test this in a fresh child theme with no other code.

How would one disable the breadcrumbs from a child theme?

Comment: I guess for an updated answer, it's now `20` as per this guide: https://wpza.net/how-to-remove-breadcrumbs-in-woocommerce/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copy and paste the following snippet into your functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'z_remove_wc_breadcrumbs');

function z_remove_wc_breadcrumbs() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10);
}
```

Comment: Please include some explanation on why this should work.

Comment: This no longer works (for me, at least) on latest versions of woocommerce / storefront.

Comment: The new hook for this is `storefront_before_content`

Comment: woocommerce_breadcrumb function is hooked into **"storefront_before_content"** with a priority of 10. So you have to remove **woocommerce_breadcrumb** function from "storefront_before_content" hook.   
Then you have to **tell WordPress when to execute** this line of code that removes woocommerce_breadcrumb from "storefront_before_content". In order to do that, you need to insert this line within a function ( in my case **z_remove_wc_breadcrumbs** ) and then hook this function to WordPress **init** hook.  
So WordPress will remove woocommerce_breadcrumb as soon as the **init** is executed.

Answer (score 6):

since Storefront 2.3.1 try this

```
add_action('init', 'dp_remove_wc_breadcrumbs');

function dp_remove_wc_breadcrumbs(){
    remove_action('storefront_before_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_get_breadcrumb’, ‘__return_false’ );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it is still there.

Answer (score -1):

```
.breadcrumb{
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: That would just hide them on the browser. There will still be there in the code. It is a possible workaround though.