# Remove breadcrumbs from Storefront theme in Woocommerce 3.3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, breadcrumbs

Up until a recent update (for Woocommerce, and also the Storefront theme), I was able to remove breadcrumbs using the following code in the child theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'z_remove_storefront_breadcrumb' );
function z_remove_storefront_breadcrumb() {
remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb',  10 );
```

That solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45118245/1092677).

Since the update (and I am not sure if it was the WC or SF update that did it) this no longer works.

I also tried the other method suggested in the above-mentioned post. And a few other methods, all listed here:

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_get_breadcrumb’, ‘__return_false’ );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
```

and

```
add_action( 'init', 'jk_remove_storefront_breadcrumb' );
function jk_remove_storefront_breadcrumb() {
remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb',  10 );
}
```

also

```
add_action( 'init', 'woo_remove_wc_breadcrumbs' );
function woo_remove_wc_breadcrumbs() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
}
```

also

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_get_breadcrumb’, ‘__return_false’ );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
```

also

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'remove_breadcrumbs');
function remove_breadcrumbs() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
}
```

Can anyone suggest what the current way to remove breadcrumbs from the Storefront theme is?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I finally find the answer. The following code will remove the Storefront theme breadcrumbs:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs');

function wc_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs() {
  remove_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10 );
}
```